Having Trouble of Capturing the XHR Request with Selenium
First of all I'm not a developer, so used ai to generate me a code to get xhr requests from a webpage which is: https://www.oddsportal.com/football/brazil/serie-a/bragantino-athletico-pr-xx0ujiJ5/
This is a sample only. I want to get scores from a xhr request on that page instead of other methods like locating it with class etc.
The most interesting thing for me is when you open the web page the network request I want to get does not appear until you click to another tab or desktop and return to target page, there appears the request I need. That request's response will provide me the match score data there.
Here is the selenium code, it captures some requests, but not the one I look for. The code will tell you my situation here. I must use only opera browser with chrome dev tools due to the web page's accecibility from my country. Giving this info but I do not believe it is the case, because this code is getting some of the requests, listing them on the terminal. If anyone simulates this, please help me.
Below is the my py file's code. I was expecting from the code to capture request name: 1-xx0ujiJ5-yj3ae.dat which its url is: https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch-score/1-xx0ujiJ5-yj3ae.dat
import json
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    Paths
    driver_path = r'C:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\drivers\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'
    binary_path = r'C:\Users\tugbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\opera.exe'

    Set up Chrome options for Opera
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = binary_path
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")  # Automatically open DevTools
    options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:9222"  # Connect to the existing Opera instance

    Enable Performance logging
    options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})

    Initialize the WebDriver service
    service = Service(driver_path)

    Initialize the WebDriver with options and capabilities
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    Enable Network logging
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})

    def capture_network_logs(duration=60):
    start_time = time.time()
    captured_urls = set()
    print(f"Capturing network logs for {duration} seconds...")
    while time.time() - start_time < duration:
    logs = driver.get_log('performance')
    for entry in logs:
    log = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
    if log['method'] == 'Network.requestWillBeSent':
    request = log['params']['request']
    if 'url' in request and request['url'] not in captured_urls:
    print(f"Request URL: {request['url']}")
    print(f"Request Method: {request['method']}")
    print(f"Request Headers: {json.dumps(request['headers'], indent=2)}")
    print("=" * 80)
    captured_urls.add(request['url'])
    time.sleep(1)  # Sleep for a short while before capturing logs again

    try:
    Open a new tab in the existing Opera window
    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    Open the target URL in the new tab
    url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/football/brazil/serie-a/bragantino-athletico-pr-xx0ujiJ5/'
    driver.get(url)

    Wait until the page is loaded
    time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds to ensure the page is fully loaded

    Inspect an element to trigger the DevTools
    driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body').click();")

    Wait a bit to ensure the element is inspected
    time.sleep(5)

    Refresh the page to ensure all requests are captured
    driver.refresh()

    Wait until the page is loaded again
    time.sleep(10)

    Click on the second opened tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

    Wait a bit in the second tab
    time.sleep(5)

    Switch back to the target tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    Wait a bit to ensure the switch is complete
    time.sleep(5)

    Capture and print network logs for 1 minute (60 seconds)
    capture_network_logs(duration=60)

    finally:
    Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()



this code require better formating

Make sure your Opera browser is configured to allow WebDriver integration and DevTools access.( options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:9222" )
The XHR request might be triggered by specific user actions or page interactions (like switching tabs or focusing the window). Since it doesn't appear until you interact with the page, you need to simulate those interactions programmatically in Selenium.
here is revised version of your Python script:
driver_path = r'C:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\drivers\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'
binary_path = r'C:\Users\tugbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\opera.exe'

# Set up Chrome options for Opera
options = Options()
options.binary_location = binary_path
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:9222"

# Initialize the WebDriver service
service = Service(driver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})

def capture_network_logs(duration=60):
    start_time = time.time()
    captured_urls = set()
    print(f"Capturing network logs for {duration} seconds...")
    while time.time() - start_time < duration:
        logs = driver.get_log('performance')
        for entry in logs:
            log = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
            if log['method'] == 'Network.requestWillBeSent':
                request = log['params']['request']
                if 'url' in request and request['url'].endswith('1-xx0ujiJ5-yj3ae.dat'):
                    print(f"Request URL: {request['url']}")
                    print(f"Request Method: {request['method']}")
                    print(f"Request Headers: {json.dumps(request['headers'], indent=2)}")
                    print("=" * 80)
                    return
        time.sleep(1) 

try:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/football/brazil/serie-a/bragantino-athletico-pr-xx0ujiJ5/'
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(10)

    driver.refresh()

    time.sleep(10)

    capture_network_logs(duration=60)

finally:
    driver.quit()



Below is the code's latest version which is succeeded in getting the xhr request I want. Locating that request is done, now I want to have its response. There are datas I want to extract from its response But I'm getting an error in return:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\scores.py", line 115, in <module>
    response_body = get_request_body(request_id)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\scores.py", line 88, in get_request_body
    response = driver.execute_cdp_cmd(command['cmd'], command['params'])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\clean_venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 141, in execute_cdp_cmd  
    return self.execute("executeCdpCommand", {"cmd": cmd, "params": cmd_args})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\clean_venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\clean_venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response  
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"No resource with given identifier found"}
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.183)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E1422C2+60002]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E0BCA59]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DF77EDA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DF5FEC7]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DF5E205]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DF5EBCF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DF5EB00]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DF7B363]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E01A09E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFEC28A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E00BCC7]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFEC033]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFB9657]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFBA251]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E453E2D+3278285]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E4A0190+3590448]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E4961D0+3549552]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E1F1DE6+779654]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E0C7ACF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E0C2EE4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E0C3072]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF61E0B2C4F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFFC6577374+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFFC80FCC91+33]

import subprocess
import json
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Paths
driver_path = r'C:\Users\tugbe\Desktop\basit_oddsportal\drivers\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'
binary_path = r'C:\Users\tugbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\opera.exe'

# Command to start Opera with remote debugging
command = f'"{binary_path}" --remote-debugging-port=9222'

# Start Opera with remote debugging
subprocess.Popen(command)
time.sleep(5)  # Give it some time to start

# Check if remote debugging is active
def check_remote_debugging():
    try:
        response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9222/json')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            tabs = response.json()
            print("Open tabs:", tabs)
            return tabs
        else:
            print("Failed to access remote debugging interface.")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None

# Verify remote debugging
tabs_before = check_remote_debugging()

# Set up Chrome options for Opera
options = Options()
options.binary_location = binary_path
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:9222"

# Enable Performance logging
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})

# Initialize the WebDriver service
service = Service(driver_path)

# Initialize the WebDriver with options and capabilities
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

requests_map = {}

def capture_network_logs(duration=60):
    start_time = time.time()
    print(f"Capturing network logs for {duration} seconds...")
    while time.time() - start_time < duration:
        logs = driver.get_log('performance')
        for entry in logs:
            log = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
            if log['method'] == 'Network.requestWillBeSent':
                request_id = log['params']['requestId']
                request = log['params']['request']
                requests_map[request_id] = request
            elif log['method'] == 'Network.responseReceived':
                response = log['params']['response']
                request_id = log['params']['requestId']
                if request_id in requests_map:
                    request = requests_map[request_id]
                    url = request['url']
                    if 'postmatch-score' in url:
                        print(f"Request URL: {url}")
                        print(f"Request Method: {request['method']}")
                        print(f"Request Headers: {json.dumps(request['headers'], indent=2)}")
                        print("=" * 80)
                        return request_id
        time.sleep(1)
    return None

def get_request_body(request_id):
    command = {
        'cmd': 'Network.getResponseBody',
        'params': {'requestId': request_id}
    }
    response = driver.execute_cdp_cmd(command['cmd'], command['params'])
    return response

try:
    # Open a new tab and navigate to the target URL
    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/football/brazil/serie-a/bragantino-athletico-pr-xx0ujiJ5/'
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the page to load

    # Refresh the page to ensure all requests are captured
    driver.refresh()

    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the page to load after refresh

    # Switch to another tab and back to trigger the XHR request
    if len(driver.window_handles) > 1:
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        time.sleep(1)

    # Capture network logs and get the specific request ID
    request_id = capture_network_logs(duration=60)
    if request_id:
        response_body = get_request_body(request_id)
        print("Response Body:")
        print(json.dumps(response_body, indent=2))

finally:
    driver.quit()

